# This code is working good for square matrix but shows error for other matrices

Tags: python, list, matrix

```
def new_matrix():
    Rows=int(input("enter number of rows:"))
    columns=int(input("enter number of columns:"))
    matrix=[[0]*Rows for _ in range(columns)]
    print (matrix)
    for k in range (columns):
        for p in range(Rows):
            matrix[k][p]=int(input("Enter elements in matrix:"))
    print (matrix)
new_matrix()
```

Output for square matrix:

```
enter number of rows:2
enter number of columns:2
[[0, 0], [0, 0]]
Enter elements in matrix:1
Enter elements in matrix:2
Enter elements in matrix:3
Enter elements in matrix:4
[[1, 2], [3, 4]]
```

Error for non-square matrix:

```
enter number of rows:1
enter number of columns:4
[[0], [0], [0], [0]]
Enter elements in matrix:1
Enter elements in matrix:2

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/kcgov/PycharmProjects/making_matrix/creating_a_matrix.py", line 10, in <module>
    new_matrix()
  File "C:/Users/kcgov/PycharmProjects/making_matrix/creating_a_matrix.py", line 8, in new_matrix
    matrix[k][p]=int(input("Enter elements in matrix:"))
IndexError: list assignment index out of range
```

Comment: I cannot reproduce your error. It works for me.

Comment: I also get no error, but it is clear that you have reversed the standard meanings of "row" and "column".

Comment: @MrGeek Oops...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to switch the Rows with columns in the matrix initialisation, and you also need to switch the loop ranges, the first one must iterate through Rows, while the second must iterate through columns in each row :

```
def new_matrix():
    Rows=int(input("enter number of rows:"))
    columns=int(input("enter number of columns:"))
    # columns, Rows
    matrix=[[0]*columns for _ in range(Rows)]
    print (matrix)
    # Rows, columns
    for k in range(Rows):
        for p in range(columns):
            matrix[k][p]=int(input("Enter elements in matrix:"))
    print (matrix)
new_matrix()
```

**Test-case *#1*: (square matrix, rows=colums)**

```
enter number of rows: 2
enter number of columns: 2
[[0, 0], [0, 0]]
Enter elements in matrix: 1
Enter elements in matrix: 2
Enter elements in matrix: 3
Enter elements in matrix: 4
[[1, 2], [3, 4]]
```

**Test-case *#2*: (rows < colums)**

```
enter number of rows: 1
enter number of columns: 4
[[0, 0, 0, 0]]
Enter elements in matrix: 1
Enter elements in matrix: 2
Enter elements in matrix: 3
Enter elements in matrix: 4
[[1, 2, 3, 4]]
```

**Test-case *#3*: (rows > colums)**

```
enter number of rows: 4
enter number of columns: 1
[[0], [0], [0], [0]]
Enter elements in matrix: 1
Enter elements in matrix: 2
Enter elements in matrix: 3
Enter elements in matrix: 4
[[1], [2], [3], [4]]
```

Comment: @KrishnaChaitanya As the author of the post, you can accept the best answer, which is the one that helped most, by ticking the checkmark under the votes so it becomes green.